# is the matrix $A$ positive-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

For $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, let $$\phi_i(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac{x(L-x_i)}{L} \text{ , for  } 0\leq x\leq x_i\\
\frac{\displaystyle x_i(L-x)}{L} \text{ , for  } x_i\leq x\leq L \end{cases}$$
and
$$\beta_{ij}=\int_0^L\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)dx$$
where $L$ is a constant and $x_i$ are given values, with $0\leq x_i \leq L$. Is the matrix $A$, with elements $a_{ij}$ given by $a_{ij}=\beta_{ij}$, positive-definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is a [gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) for the inner product 
$$
\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^L f(x)g(x) dx
$$
so in particular your matrix is positive semi-definite, but it suffice to prove that our matrix is invertible, or equivalently that is determinant is nonzero, but using the fact that our matrix is a gram matrix [this is equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix#Gram_determinant) to the fact that our functional $\phi_i(x)$ are linearly independent, and this is evident for $x_i\neq x_j $ for all $i,j\leq n$.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! However, what I saw is that the Gramian Matrix is _positive semidefinite_. By trying the approach using the fact that, for any vector $v$, we should have $v^TAv>0$ in order to prove positive-definiteness, I've reached the same result, even though my concern is whether $A$ is invertible (being positive semidefinite, I can not guarantee that anymore)

Comment: i will edit my answer to complete it @LuanGabriel

Comment: Hey @Hamza!Yet, since $A$ is positive semidefinite, it is _insufficient_ to say that it is invertible. I was confused whether the set of functions $\{\phi_1(x),\ldots,\phi_n(x)\}$ is linearly independet, because using the Wronskian approach it became pretty obvious that $W=0$, which would mean that the set is L.D anywhere in $[0,L]$. _ps_: the motivation of the problem is physical, i.e, $A$ _should_ be invertible, because in the physical problem it relates the reactions to a load in a beam (for a given load, the reactions _should_ be determined).

Comment: no i use here the fact that a matrix $A$ is positive definite iff $A$ is positive semidefinite and invertible, and this is equivalent to $\{\phi_i\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Sorry @Hanza, but I think you didn't understand me: it's not given that $A$ is invertible, and besides that how can I prove the linear independency of $\phi_i (x)$? Wronskian gives $W=0$...

Comment: For instance: $$W = 
 \begin{vmatrix}
  \phi_1(x) & \phi_2(x) & \cdots & \phi_n(x) \\
  \phi'_1(x) & \phi'_2(x) & \cdots & \phi'_n(x) \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots  \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 
 \end{vmatrix}_{n\times n}=0$$

Comment: your function are not differentiable to use Wronskian, however you can prove it using simpler linear algebra techniques

Comment: Sorry, that's completely true...yet if you can give any hint on how to use some simpler technique to prove that I'd appreciate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45676/discussion-between-luan-gabriel-and-hamza).